# Getting the subsite an item came from after performing spsitedataquery

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have the following code:

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

                //Get List query string

                query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1'></Lists>";


                query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='ContentType' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='ArticleStartDate' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='Synopsis' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='PublishingRollupImage' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='Location' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='LOBGroup' Nullable='TRUE' />";
                query.Query = "<Where>" +
                                  "<Contains>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>" +
                                    "<Value Type='Text'>DCP_Article</Value>" +
                                  "</Contains>" +
                                "</Where>";



                query.Query += "<OrderBy>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='ArticleStartDate' Descending='TRUE' />" +
                                "</OrderBy>";


                query.RowLimit = Convert.ToUInt32(loadsize);
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive' />";


                //Get Site Data from web
                DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

In my results I would like to get the Subsite that the item came from, I understand that if I use `query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='FileRef' Nullable='TRUE' />";` I can get the full url of the item, but is there anyway I can just get the subsite it came from? something like this:
`query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='SiteName' Nullable='TRUE' />";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
query.ViewFields += "<ProjectProperty Name=\"Title\" />";
```

For more information, see [SPSiteDataQuery.ViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.viewfields.aspx):

> Site properties may be included by using the ProjectProperty tag. The Name attribute of the ProjectProperty tag identifies the specific property and may contain one of the following values:
>
> - Title -- the title of the Web site that contains the item.
> - WebId -- the GUID of the Web site that contains the item.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on both EncodedAbsUrl and FileRef to retrieve the web. The first one will contain the whole path to the item and the second one only the partial part (if I remember well). Doing a substring should thus give you the path of the web where the item is hosted.

I'm sorry I don't have my VM in front of me but if you look with a tool like SharePoint Explorer / Manager, you'll see all hidden list item fields and you'll be able to grab the one that is closest to your solution (but my safe best of relying on EncodedAbsUrl and FileRef is trusty)

Answer (score 0):

And yet another option is to use WebId column which will be included in your resultset.
This is a guid which you can use to open the web the result came from:

```
Guid webGuid = new Guid(row["WebId"].ToString());
using(SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs[webGuid])
{
     //Do some thing with the SPWeb
}
```